# What does "The grass is greener on the other side" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> The grass is greener on the other side.

Can you guys explain this sentence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a proverb:

[The grass is always greener on the other side of the fence](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/the-grass-is-always-greener-on-the-other-side-of-the-fence)

> People are never satisfied with their own situation; they always think others have it better.

(Dictionary.com)

> The idiom derives from a more recent version of an ancient proverb and exists in many variations. The Roman poet Ovid, for example, cited the proverb “ferilor seges est alienis semper in agris,” meaning “the harvest is always more fruitful in another man’s field.” ***Although dozens of versions of the proverb can be found, “the grass is always greener” is the favorite American way of expressing the sentiment.*** It is speculated that the expression came from the habit of cattle of grazing through the fence on the grass of the adjacent field, or escaping from one pasture to another through a broken fence line, in search of new grass to eat.

(Idiomsonline.com)

Comment: I think it's like "I dont like my country. That country is better." but when he went to that country to live it's like "I miss my country. This country is too bad to live, I want to go back." Did I understand it?

Comment: @ÖzgünErdemCeylan - yes, it may express  also that concept. It always comes down to the idea that others are in a better condition than you are.

Comment: well, it's a proverb that often said to remind someone that just because the situation of the other(s) might looks better than what they have, that doesn't mean it all is.  Since it's often easier to envy what looks better about the other situation, than understanding what's worse about it.

Comment: I like the cow grazing origin hypothesis, but I have always visualized this proverb in a suburban lawn-care setting.  As in:  "I water, I fertilize, I aerate, I pull up every dandelion as soon as I see it, I carefully mow and keep the mower's blades well honed.  But somehow, someway, Dave-the-Neighbor's lawn always looks nicer.   (Grumble grumble stupid Dave.)"  Good or bad, it's a very American way of thinking.

Comment: @ÖzgünErdemCeylan No. The proverb doesn't really mean that on its own. Applied to that particular situation, it doesn't say the person has at some point been to that other country. It just means that one always thinks that others have it better. (But this is obviously an absurd sentiment because if everyone thinks that about everyone else...)

Comment: @ÖzgünErdemCeylan - I suppose one could use this proverb to speak about two countries, but it's more often applied so something like, say, two different jobs – as when someone leaves their job for another job only to discover that their first place of employment wasn't so bad after all.

Comment: @J.R. - I think  the sense of the  “two countries” example the OP is making is related to what’s been happening in Europe in recent years, where a lot of young people from south or east Europe are attracted by countries like Germany or other northern  countries where economic conditions are better, but lifestyle and different cultures often make it a very difficult choice.

Comment: @user070221 - You could be right, and the proverb would definitely be apt for that scenario. (I just wanted to make it clear that it need not apply to two _locations_ per se.)